# Fitnesse ScenarioLibrary is not being included in the tests

Tags: tdd, automated-tests, fitnesse

When creating a ScenarioLibrary, it is not being automatically added in the tests.
Here is the structure of the tests:

- FrontPage

  - ScenarioLibrary
  - Tests suite

    - Test A
    - Test B

The ScenarioLibrary contains the scenario table that I am supposed to use in the tests

Test A and Test B contains DecisionTable, where i call the scenarios created in the ScenarioLibrary. However, the ScenarioLibrary page is not being included in the Test A and Test B.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Below is the content of the pages

**ScenarioLibrary**

```
    !define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!path C:\fitnesse\myJar.jar

!|scenario|Login|action|With|parameters|Expected|result|
|check|issueHttpRequestWithParams;|login|@parameters|@result|
```

**Test A** (only contains a Decision table that calls the Scenario created

```
!|Login With Expected|
|parameters                                              |result        |
|{"username":"testUser","password":"testPassword"}       |{"status":"success"}    |
```

When i save Test A, the ScenarioLibrary page is not included within it as the Setup page.

Comment: Can you post the content of your pages and the output?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Mike. Please find my Update in the description above.

Answer (score 1):

The ScenarioLibrary is only included if the test page it self is a Slim test. This is documented under ScenarioLibrary in [SpecialPages](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SpecialPages). This means that `!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}` has to be defined in either the test page itself or a parent page to include the ScenarioLibrary.

If you only have Slim tests, I recommend you to define your current ScenarioContent into the root page (localhost:port/root). The content of the root page will be propagated to the rest of the wiki.

Also note this quote from ScenarioLibrary section in [SpecialPages](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SpecialPages):

> These pages are intended for scenario tables.